# MySQL query - unknown column in where clause- column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT area_id, 
           area_name,
           (select count(*) from applications
                  where claims_status=1 and 
                    center_name=c.area_id) as cont
    FROM apparea c where cont<>0
```

I am trying to get fields and relevant count from anothere table, but the above query is not working. The query is involved two different tables(apparea, applications). The above query has error and I am looking for the alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: Unknown column 'cont' in 'where clause'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias for your column `cont` is not available in the `WHERE` clause. You will want to use something similar to this:

```
SELECT area_id, 
  area_name,
  cont
FROM
(
  SELECT area_id, 
    area_name,
    (select count(*) 
     from applications
     where claims_status=1 
     and center_name=c.area_id) as cont
  FROM apparea c
) c 
where cont<>0
```

This can also be written using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select c.area_id,
  c.area_name,
  a.cont
from apparea c
left join
(
  select count(*) cont,
    center_name
  from applications
  where claims_status=1 
  group by center_name
) a
  on c.area_id = a.center_name
```

Comment: its working...another methodology i learnt today...thank you...but is this the best optimized? just asking..

Comment: @user1854007 Well the problem is that when you provide an alias for something in the `SELECT` it is not available in the `WHERE` so you have to work around it.  The second version with the `LEFT JOIN` could also be changed to an `INNER JOIN` if you are sure you will always have a matching row in the `applications` table.  There are many ways to write queries, you just need to figure out what will work best for your situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
     c.area_id,
     c.area_name,
     cnt 
FROM 
     apparea c, 
     (select 
            center_name, 
            count(*) AS cnt 
     from 
            applications
     where 
            claims_status=1 
     GROUP BY 
            center_name
     HAVING 
            count(*) > 0)  cont
where 
     c.area_id = cont.center_name;
```

Got the count for each center_name and then joined table to get count for each area

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.cnt' in 'field list'   .......i have changed c.cont<>0 to c.cnt<>0...

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` rather than `where`.

As it is problem with `aliases`.

```
It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column
value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed. 
See Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

**From:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html